# Getting error foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '' because '' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting an error here in my razor view:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'Project.Model.ResultsClass' because 'Project.Model.ResultsClass' does
>   not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Here is my `foreach` and how I am defining `Model`

```
@model Project.Models.ResultsClass

@foreach (var item in Model) {
}
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult Results()
{
    var results = db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Results").ToList();
    ResultsClass result = new ResultsClass();

    result.previewID = results[0].id;
    result.dateSlot = results[0].dateSlot;
    result.timeSlot = results[0].timeSlot;
    result.startTime = results[0].startTime;
    result.dateCreated = results[0].dateCreated;

    return View(result);
}
```

And Here is my class:

```
public class ResultsClass
{
    [DisplayName("Preview ID")]
    public int previewID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public string dateSlot { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Time")]
    public string timeSlot { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Completed Time")]
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your view is strongly typed to a single instance of `ResultsClass`. Not a collection. Why are you looping if you are not passing a collection ?

Comment: Ahhhh I see. So I need to pass the variable result to my view so I can loop through it?

Comment: yes. return View(results) and change the view to have a collection of `ResultsClass`

Comment: Why do you *expect* to be able to loop over a single object?  What behavior do you expect this to produce?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've passed the `result` which is a type of `ResultsClass` not a collection of `ResultsClass`, and then attempt to iterate over it as if it were a collection so you can't use it in your `foreach` loop. So in order to be able to use [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) on it, you have to make it a collection. For example your `foreach` loop works if you would passed `results` instead of `result`:

```
return View(results);

@model List<Project.Models.ResultsClass>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh I see. So I need to pass the variable result to my view so I can loop through it?

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
@model Project.Models.ResultsClass
```

That line then leads to problems in your controller action if you are wanting to return a list (collection) to the view.

Basically in the view, that line means that you are wanting to show 1 `ResultsClass` object.. not a collection of `ResultsClass` objects, so you can't iterate over just 1 `ResultsClass` object.

But for now, you could resolve that issue by just calling the properties of the `ResultsClass` object you're returning to the view.

```
@model Project.Models.ResultsClass

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.previewID)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateSlot)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeSlot)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startTime)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateCreated)
```

**OR**

Just pass the `results` object in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Results()
{
    var results = db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Results").ToList();
    return View(results);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ResultsClass>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    // .. display properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your model is not a collection. It is an object. If you want to iterate over something it must be a collection like an array or a list.

Try this:

```
@model Project.Models.ResultsClass

@foreach (var item in Model.result) {
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh I see. So I need to pass the variable result to my view so I can loop through it?

Comment: It sounds like that is what you wish to do. Otherwise you could leave it as is and change your loop to @foreach (var item in Model.result){ }

Comment: Can you show some code to better define your answer.